# Regex for a specific format ( javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write a regex to validate a particular format

lets say I have version numbers

```
v1.0   or v2.0
```

etc , my regex expression just checks for the presence of `v` or a `number` or `.` , how do I do a validation for a particular format in javascript

Comment: Versioning takes on many shapes. If you don't know all the permutationsd, the best you could do (in your case) is `[vV][.\d]+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/^v\d+(\.\d+)+$/i
```

This will match:

1. v1.0
2. v1.12.13
3. v1.0.1.0.1.0.1

etc.

Comment: This won't match `v` or `V1` or `v.5` or `This is v-9.0`

Comment: @sln: Slightly modified regex `/^v\d+(\.\d+)*$/i` can take care of it I believe.

Comment: actually I have a pretty fixed format for the version number and your first regex was perfect , Thank you for your help